# PHP find string1 within string2 where string1 is derived from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a profanity filter implemented in my PHP app that checks strings a user sends from a browser client against a list of profane words stored as a table in MySQL. The table looks like this:

```
Word
badWord1
badWord2
etc.
```

The PHP code is as follows:

```
SELECT word FROM Profanities WHERE word REGEXP '$stringToCheck';
```

It works fine if a user enters a profanity (or a sequence of profanities), so:

```
badWord1
```

This is picked up correctly.

```
badWord1 badWord2
```

This is also picked up correctly. However, this is not picked up:

```
badWord1badWord2
```

Is there any way to compare the above string against all profane words in my table?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: This couldn't possibly go wrong in a [clbuttic](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html) way. There is no such thing as a profanity filter that works. It will really get on the nerves of legitimate people, and will not stop people who know how to work around it.

Comment: Would you believe I worked for AOL in 1996 and actually pointed out the Scunthorpe problem? My solution here is to flag whenever this occurs so that a human can pick it up and review it. So, the algorithm is the "first line of defence", with a human reviewing what was entered in case there is a valid exception.

Comment: Thanks tadman, but that's not good logic. Just because something doesn't work perfectly, doesn't mean we should simply ignore the problem and hope for the best. I don't want kids to be exposed to profane language, so any barriers I put up will help. Sure people can circumvent it if they really try, but does that mean I shouldn't try to make it harder for people?

Comment: These filters have been in place long enough that people know how to work around them by using increasingly obscure slurs. "I like shitake mushrooms" gets flagged but "I will hunt you down you miserable (obscure slur)" does not.

Comment: Again, I'm happy for people to try and "work around it". I need a good first line of defence so that it's not trivial for people to enter profanities.

Comment: Sure, but unless you have any code this is all just wishful thinking and is really off-topic.

Comment: Well "shittake mushrooms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going at it backwards. You don't compare each word in the text against the database. Instead, you search the entire text for any of the bad words. You can turn all the bad words into a regular expression, e.g.

```
$badwords = '/badword1|badword2|badword3|.../i';
```

Then you do:

```
if (preg_match($badwords, $text)) {
    // complain about language
}
```

You can create the regexp with:

```
SELECT CONCAT('/', GROUP_CONCAT(word SEPARATOR '|'), '/') AS badwords
FROM wordlist
```